# how to read latest unread emails from outlook till the point i have read mail

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

i am trying to read unread mails from my outlook mailbox using powershell and displaying subject.  i want to read latest  unread emails till the point i have any read email. i may have unread emails after read mails but that should not be included.

```
  $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
  $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
  $folder=$namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
  $folder.Items|ForEach-Object { 
  if($_.Unread -eq $true){
    $_.subject
 }else{
break;
}  
 }
```

Since my inbox is full of mails(11011+ )mails so the above script is getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class if you need to find only unread items in the folder.

### Find/FindNext

```
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
// ...
private void FindAllUnreadEmails(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
    string searchCriteria = "[UnRead] = true";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
    int counter = default(int);
    Outlook._MailItem mail = null;
    Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
    object resultItem = null;
    try
    {
        if (folder.UnReadItemCount > 0)
        {
            strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            folderItems = folder.Items;
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria);
            while (resultItem != null)
            {
                if (resultItem is Outlook._MailItem)
                {
                    counter++;
                    mail = resultItem as Outlook._MailItem;
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + 
                                          "\tSubject: " + mail.Subject);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem);
                resultItem = folderItems.FindNext();
            }
            if (strBuilder != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " 
                                 + folder.Name + " folder.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
    }
}
```

### Restrict

```
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
// ...
private void RestrictUnreadItems(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
    string restrictCriteria = "[UnRead] = true";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
    Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
    Outlook.Items resultItems = null;
    Outlook._MailItem mail = null;
    int counter = default(int);
    object item = null;
    try
    {
        strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        folderItems = folder.Items;
        resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
        item = resultItems.GetFirst();
        while (item != null)
        {
            if (item is Outlook._MailItem)
            {
                counter++;
                mail = item as Outlook._MailItem;
                strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() +
                                   "\tSubject: " + mail.Subject);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
            item = resultItems.GetNext();
        }
        if (strBuilder.Length > 0)
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the "
                             + folder.Name + " folder.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
        if (resultItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItems);
    }
}
```

You can read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Pre-filter within Outlook with Restrict():

```
...
$folder=$namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$folder.Items.Restrict('[UnRead] = True')|ForEach-Object { 
  $_.subject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the solution using `Restrict()`. When you query the items like this:

```
$mails = $namespace.Folders.Item("emailAddress").Folders.Item("Inbox").[...].Items.Restrict('[UnRead] = True')
$mails.Sort( "[ReceivedTime]", $true)
```

and finally process it within a `foreach`, modifying the `UnRead` Property, you'll end up with an incomplete processing, because you are actually modifying the collection, while processing it.

Not good:

```
foreach ($mails as $mail){
    [...]
    $mail.UnRead = $false #Modifying this will cause the foreach to skip items
}
```

So, when using restrict, reverse iterate the collection to make sure, you'll process all items:

```
for ($i = $mails.Count; $i -gt 0; $i--){  
    $mail = $mails[$i]
    [...]
    $mail.UnRead = $False
}
```